# How to unnest irregular JSON data

Tags: r, json, unnest

I have been looking at many solutions on this site to similar problems for weeks but cannot wrap my head around how to apply them successfully to this particular one:

I have the dataset at https://statdata.pgatour.com/r/006/player_stats.json

using:

```
player_stats_url<-"https://statdata.pgatour.com/r/006/player_stats.json"
player_stats_json <- fromJSON(player_stats_url)
player_stats_df <- ldply(player_stats_json,data.frame)
```

gives:
a dataframe of 145 rows, one for each player, and 7 columns, the 7th of which is named "players.stats" that contains the data I'd like broken out into a 2-dimensional dataframe

next, I do this to take a closer look at the "players.stats" column:

```
player_stats_df2<- ldply(player_stats_df$players.stats, data.frame)
```

the data in the "players.stats" columns are formatted as follows: rows of
25 repeating stat categories in the column (`player_stats_df2$name`) and another nested list in the column `$rounds` ... on which I repeat ldply to unnest everything but I cannot sew it back together logically in the way that I want ...

the format of the column `$rounds`, after unnested, using:

```
    player_stats_df3<- ldply(player_stats_df2$rounds, data.frame)
```

gives the round number in the first column `$r` (1,2,3,4 as only choices) and then the stat value in the second column `$rValue`. to complicate things, some entries have 2 rounds, while others have 4 rounds

the final format of the 2-dimensional dataframe I need would have columns named players.pid and players.pn from player_stats_df, a NEW COLUMN denoting "round.no" which would correspond to `player_stats_df3$r` and then  each of the 25 repeating stat categories from `player_stats_df2$name` as a column (eagles, birdies, pars ... SG: Off-the-tee, SG: tee-to-green, SG: Total) and each row being unique to a player name and round number ...

For example, there would be four rows for Matt Kuchar, one for each round played, and a column for each of the 25 stat categories ... However, some other players would only have 2 rows.

Please let me know if I can clarify this at all for this particular example- I have tried many things but cannot sew this data back together in the format I need to use it in ...

Answer (score 0):

Here something you can start with, we can create a `tibble` using `tibble::as_tibble` then apply multiple unnest using `tidyr::unnest`

```
library(tidyverse)
as_tibble(player_stats_json$tournament$players) %>% unnest() %>% unnest(rounds)
```

Also see this tutorial [here](https://jennybc.github.io/purrr-tutorial/ls02_map-extraction-advanced.html). Finally use `dplyr` "`tidyverse`" instead of `plyr`